# Multiple where in same table mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'option_product'  on MYSQL

```
Id  id_product   id_option   id_value
1   1             34          77
2   2             34          74
3   1             2           12          
4   2             2           10
5   3             2           18
```

i want do something like that

```
select id from option_product where 

id_option = 34 and id_value = 77

and 

(id_option=2 and id value= 12 or id_option=2 and id value= 5)
```

How can I do that?

**the query should return  the id_product that  have all conditions   for exemple  if( id_option = 34 and id_value=77) and ( id_option=2 and id_value=12 or  id_option=2 and id_value=10)  it will return id_product =  1**

Comment: How can `id_Option` equal 34 and 2?

Comment: The field id_option of a row can't be 34 and 2 at the same time as your example suggests.  Do you mean `WHERE (id_option=34 AND id_value=77) OR (id_option=2 AND id_value=...) OR (...)`?

Comment: How it will return 1 for 2 / 10 combination, when there stands 2 for id_product?

Comment: can i do this with programming  ( php / Algorithm )

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id
From option_product
Where (id_option = 34 And id_value = 77) Or (id_option = 2 And id_value In (12, 5))
```

This will get you rows that contains (option_id, id_value) -> (34, 77), (2, 12) and (2, 5)

Comment: This will never gives you back any result.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, let me change it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really mean is this:

```
select id from option_product where (id_option = 34 and id_value = 77)
OR (id_option=2 and id value= 12)
OR (id_option=2 and id value= 5)
```

Comment: i want  to do a filter in the same time with condition  if( id_option= x  and id_value= x )

Comment: OK, in that case, can you please edit your question to show which rows the query should return?

Comment: OK, so in other words, you want rows where id_option contains the same value as id_value.  In that case, you would do: select id from option_product where id_option=id_value;  But, you don't have any rows in the option_product table, where id_option contains the same value as id_value, so the query would return zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  select id from option_product where 
  (id_option = 34 and id_value = 77)
  or
  (id_option=2 and (id_value= 12 or id_value= 5) )
```

Comment: this query will return  id_product 1 and id_product  2

Comment: select id_product from (
select id_product from option_product where 
  (id_option = 34 and id_value = 77)
union all
select id_product from option_product where 
  (id_option=2 and (id_value= 12 or id_value= 5) )
) as t where count(t.id_product)>1

Comment: even the secound condition is not realized because of "or"

Comment: please try above query

Comment: i corrected, please try this.. select id_product from ( select id_product from option_product where id_option = 34 and id_value = 77 union all select id_product from option_product where id_option=2 and (id_value= 12 or id_value= 5)  ) as t having count(t.id_product)>1

Comment: thanks i need one more specific thing  how can i do if i have more than 2 conditions for exemple  id_option = 34 and id_value = 77  and id_option = 34 and id_value = 74  and id_option=2 and id_value= 5 ....

Comment: Yeah, you can do this : 
select id_product from ( select id_product from option_product where id_option = 34 and (id_value = 77 or id_value = 74) union all select id_product from option_product where id_option=2 and (id_value= 12 or id_value= 5) ) as t having count(t.id_product)>2

Comment: !! this query return just one result id_product = 1  :(

Comment: ohh...try this : select id_product from ( select id_product from option_product where id_option = 34 and id_value = 77 union all 
 select id_product from option_product where id_option = 34 and id_value = 74 union all select id_product from option_product where id_option=2 and (id_value= 12 or id_value= 10) ) as t group by id_product

Comment: it's work but this query dont go the second condition  union all select id_product from option_product where id_option=2 and (id_value= 12 or id_value= 10) )  !!???

Comment: this query must return  just id_product = 1  :  select id_product from ( select id_product from option_product where id_option = 34 and id_value = 77 union all select id_product from option_product where id_option = 34 and id_value = 74 union all select id_product from option_product where id_option=2 and (id_value= 12 or id_value= 88) ) as t group by  id_product

Comment: @ZakariaeLyzouli if you got the answer then please accept it.